# Exclude react, react-dom from webpack bundle for building react library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to exclude react, react-dom from webpack bundle. I tried to use webpack external liek below

```
externals: {
        react: {
            root: 'React',
            commonjs2: 'react',
            commonjs: 'react',
            amd: 'react'
        },
        'react-dom': {
            root: 'ReactDOM',
            commonjs2: 'react-dom',
            commonjs: 'react-dom',
            amd: 'react-dom'
        }
    }
```

It works as expected and does remove react, react-dom from bundle file. But when I try to load this bundle file in another application as shown below, it throws **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined**

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        var loadJS = function(url, implementationCode, location){
            var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
            scriptTag.src = url;
            scriptTag.onload = implementationCode;
            scriptTag.onreadystatechange = implementationCode;
            scriptTag.onerror = () => alert("Failed to load script");
            location.appendChild(scriptTag);
        };
        var yourCodeToBeCalled = function(data, resp) {
            var React = require('react');
            var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

            global.React = React;
            global.ReactDOM = ReactDOM;

            console.log(window);

            const Posts = window.ReactComponent.SampleComponent;
            return setPosts(<Posts />)
        };
        
        setTimeout(() => {
            loadJS('http://localhost:4000//dist/sampleComponent.js', yourCodeToBeCalled, document.body);
        }, 1000);
    });

    return (
        <div>
            Sample REACT application | Testing
            {posts}
        </div>
    )
```

I havent included the CDN links in the parent application as REACT, REACTDOM is already available. I am not sure why it is not picking react, react-dom which is already available in parent application. Help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was to expose React to window object so that it is accessible to sub app

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
window.React = React;
```